# ov2640 with 18 pin and no arducam shield

Tags: arduino-due, camera

I bought this ov2640 camera module with 18 pins and I don't have shield to insert it to. I am looking for a library or working code on this my camera sensor but all I kept getting was arducam examples or at most ov7670 example code. Can anybody help me out here?
The image of the module is at this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUVg0.jpg

PS: I am using an arduino due

(Edit: Added image of camera module)
[image]

Comment: not an Arduino specific question

Comment: @jsotola, sorry, why would this be not arduino specific? the questions asks how to wire a camera module to Arduino Due without the Arduino shield usually used for this type of camera

Comment: I am using arduino due

Answer (score -1):

There is a datasheet for the module at https://www.mpja.com/download/35647mpdata.pdf

It references the Arducam library at https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/ArduCAM.

The library specifically supports this camera type. By studying the camera specific code you may get a better idea of what is required. To connect the module directly to a Due, the work that was designed to be done by the intended shield would need to be replicated. Which seems non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you. I had a headway. The library can help you connect to the ov2640 camera and communicate with it through sccb interface. There is a whole lot of spi interface configuration that doesn't apply in my own case, so I didn't use the spi pin. Getting the snapshot of what is in the D0 - D7 pins without an assistant of library is not as trivial for a learner as you think. I am using arduino due and would like to facilaitate this using DMA. I want to send the snapshot straight to sd card.

Comment: You’re welcome, I’m glad the suggestion helped you progress. As I thought, non-trivial (i.e., complicated).  A further suggestion might be to finalize the basics of interfacing directly to the camera before introducing DMA? It may be worth a separate question on the DMA idea? If you resolve the direct interface you might consider posting an answer to this question, I’m sure there will be other readers interested in how you did it.